# Arduino controlling high voltage DC source, Opto-Isolator

Tags: arduino, high-voltage, opto-isolator

I need to create a circuit that I can use an Arduino to control a 400~500 DC voltage source.
I am not used to opto-isolators, but I was thinking about using it to separate both systems. But I cant seem to find one that can handle 500V DC in the Vcc port.
My thought process(I am not sure how to create and opto-isolator, so assume the LED and transistor in the middle are the opto-isolator):
If you guys know a better way to completely separate both systems please give me your input.
BTW the current is very low, below 1mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgMjwr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: R2 looks a bit low to me.

Comment: I am sorry: the resistors values are just random for now. I just need some input on the opto-coupler, or a way to separate  the circuits.

Comment: An opto-isolator does consist of an LED and a transistor (or sometimes a more complex circuit).  The first thing you have to do is to determine how the 500 volt source is controlled - I suspect that the controlling device does not actually have to switch 500 volts, but until we know tha actual control circuit, I don't think we can make any useful suggestions.  Also - is the control only on/off, or do you need to adjust the voltage as well?

Comment: The 500v comes from a high voltage power supply. So you just set the voltage and click the on button(that simple). The arduino side is only an on/off.

Comment: To safely and reliably interface with this supply, we need to know the voltage and current that the "On/Off" button switches.

Comment: It switches 500v DC. The controlling device needs to switch 500v DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If response times in the ms are acceptable, you could use an optically coupled pair of back-to-back MOSFETs such as the [CPC1393GRTR](http://www.clare.com/home/pdfs.nsf/0/498F5B361C9102A48525720B0055FE67/$file/CPC1393.pdf).

[image]

This particular one can switch 600V at up to 90mA, with maximum on/off times of 5ms and maximum 'off' leakage of 1uA. It would typically drop less than 100mV at a few mA.

Isolation voltage input-to-output is 5000V claimed, you'll have to evaluate if that's safe enough for your application.

Comment: Can I ask you what would the circuit look like? I am not familiar with Solid State Relays.

Comment: And this seems to be exactly what I need looking at the data sheet. ms would work just fine. Can you please help me with the circuit? Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThiagoOmena have you even bothered looking online for opto-isolator example circuits? they are very straight forward. Just make sure you read the max current rating for the LED for it's resistor.

Comment: I have but I never seen a Dual MOSFET opto isolator. Better ask and be safe than sorry. 500v DC can do a lot of damage. I looked for circuits for this specific opto but I couldn't find any circuits.

Comment: You would just use it in the circuit you showed, with an appropriate load and with a series resistor to limit the LED current to levels shown on the datasheet. Since the MOSFETs can handle AC or DC, the polarity on the MOSFET side is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can a regular 1/2 Watts resistor handle 500v without breaking down?(Assuming it will be dissipating 1/4 Watts) P=I^2*R=(1mA)^2*(250Kohms)

Comment: For reliability I suggest using [Vishay VR25](http://www.vishay.com/docs/28732/vr25.pdf) resistors.

Comment: Thanks guys. I had to switch the opto because it was hard to find, but thanks for helping me understand how this works. It worked out perfectly.